# How to use protractor to get the response status code and response text?

Tags: protractor

I'm using [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/) for e2e testing.

I want to visit a url, say:

```
browser.get("http://my.test.com");
```

And get the http status code and all the response body text, but I can't find a way to get them. Is there any methods I can use?

Comment: There is a wdio-intercept-service library but I noticed it doesn't work for me on Protractor.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Getting the http status code it's not possible since [it's been resolved that selenium webdriver API won't add it](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141) and Protractor depends on Selenium for interacting with the browser.

You'll need to find a workaround for this, e.g. using NodeJS given that Protractor runs inside it with a helper function that understand promises so Protractor waits for the http get before continuing:

```
// A Protracterized httpGet() promise
function httpGet(siteUrl) {
    var http = require('http');
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

    http.get(siteUrl, function(response) {

        var bodyString = '';

        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        
        response.on("data", function(chunk) {
            bodyString += chunk;
        });
        
        response.on('end', function() {
            defer.fulfill({
                statusCode: response.statusCode,
                bodyString: bodyString
            });
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        defer.reject("Got http.get error: " + e.message);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}

it('should return 200 and contain proper body', function() {
    httpGet("http://localhost:80").then(function(result) {
        expect(result.statusCode).toBe(200);
        expect(result.bodyString).toContain('Apache');
    });
});
```

Other option might be changing the html server side accordingly to the response status code as in [this blog post](https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-get-the-http-status-code-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
<h1 id="web_403">403 Access Denied</h1>
```

Comment: Leo I think the link you have added to shows differently. Is this still the case?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to look into this old post, if there is a better more up-to-date answer please fill in and I'll up vote if it works :) :)

Comment: it's OK. Indeed if I find a way I'll inform you and thanks for the answer. It's the one I'll try to follow as I only need some body checksums. Take care.

Comment: @LeoGallucci Can you please help in  https and post method with protractor.