# Capture server JSON response in end-to-end test

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor

I'm writing an end-to-end test that simulates user authentication with [Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/). A user feels in her credentials and clicks a Submit button. As a result, the server returns an access token in a JSON response that can be used for other REST API calls. I'd like to save this token to a file.

There's a similar question on capturing a response of a GET request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137881/how-to-use-protractor-to-get-the-response-status-code-and-response-text), but I'm not sure it's a good idea to send another request after I click the button.

How can I capture the response after a button click?

Comment: Do you have that token written to any node attribute value inside the DOM, or is it accessible through the scope?

Comment: I just get a plain JSON response, so there's no DOM to parse.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my idea about how to catch HTTP responses. *Protractor* provides a method `browser.addMockModule()` ([docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule)) - it is used to add custom *Angular* modules to a page, which are usually used to mock outcoming requests and provide custom response. But we do not need to mock requests, it would be enough to just listen for whatever comes from a server. It can be achieved with the help of *Angular HTTP [interceptors](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)*. *Interceptors* are used to catch a request or a response and modify it for whatever needs before in gets to it's endpoint. We can use them to collect information about what is coming from the server, store it, and then let response go forward without changes. Since this custom module and spec tests will run on the same page, information about responses can be stored in some global property. Then, when button is clicked, it would be possible to inject custom script to a page to retrieve required responses via `browser.executeScript()` ([docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript)). Here is the source:

```
it('should intercept requests', function () {

    // Inject custom Angular module on a page
    // Script should be injected before you "browser.get()" the page
    browser.addMockModule('e2eHttp', function () {
        // Note: This function scope is not a Protractor environment

        angular
        .module('e2eHttp', [])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            // add custom interceptor to all requests
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('e2eHttpInterceptor');
        })
        .factory('e2eHttpInterceptor', function () {
            return {
                response: function (response) {
                    // name of the global property to store responses
                    var global = 'e2eHttpResponses';
                    // responses will be grouped by url
                    // but you can use data from "response.config" to adapt it
                    // it has a lot of info about response headers, method, etc
                    var url = response.config.url;

                    window[global] = window[global] || {};
                    window[global][url] = window[global][url] || [];
                    window[global][url].push(response); // store response

                    // proceed without changing response
                    return response;
                }
            };
        });
    });

    // Load the page
    browser.get('#/auth/login');

    $('#submit').click();

    // If we are sure that response has come, then extract it

    browser.executeScript(function () {
        // Note: This function scope is not a Protractor environment

        var global = 'e2eHttpResponses';
        var uri = 'api/auth/login.json';

        // extract array of stored responses for required uri
        var responses = (window[global] && window[global][uri]) || [];

        // return responses to spec
        return responses;

    }).then(function (responses) {
        // and finally, we are now able to get all information we need
        // about response, and in your case, save it to a file

        console.log(responses);

        var data = responses[0].data; // first response body as a string
    });


    // remove injected module not to break another specs
    browser.removeMockModule('e2eHttp');
});
```

You can move setup and injection calls to some utility modules, so test specs would be clean.