# Combine E2E testing with HTTP web services testing

Tags: web-services, automated-tests, protractor, e2e-testing

Can I catch HTTP request\response from the protractor, I want to create E2E tests with validation of the web services using JSON.

Comment: can you provide more info on what you have tried and tested with?

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682047/capture-server-json-response-in-end-to-end-test/31695997

Answer (score 2):

You can only capture request, response through a proxy. Selenium-webdriver doesn't support this feature since it is limited to only browser simulation. One of the most well known proxies for inspecting request, response is [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy). You can either directly use its API or use the node client [browsermob-node](https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node). Once You have a proxy running, you can set driver capabilities in your protractor config like below

```
capabilities: {
  'proxy': {
    'proxyType': 'manual',
    'httpProxy': 'hostname.com:1234'
  }
}
```